# Swift 3d Array creating

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, swift2, swift3

I want to create an array that is 3d. Array will be 5*5*infinite (the last or the innermost array will probably has like 3-5 object of type String).

I tried something like this:

```
var array3D = [[[String]]]()
```

and tried to add new string like this

```
array3D[ii][yy] += y.components(separatedBy: ";")
```

But had problems adding new arrays or strings to that. And got error of exc bad instruction

In school I have 5 lessons per day. So in week there is 25 lessons, and I want to make an iPhone app that represent my timetable.

Comment: "But had problems adding new arrays or strings to that. And got error of exc bad instruction" That's a pity, but it's not a question. If you're having a problem with your code, _show_ your code and explain the problem.

Comment: If it's s 3D array, you need to access is with3 indices like array3D[i][j][k]

Comment: You always have to set something to `array3d[x]` before you can set anything to `array3d[x][y]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multidimensional array is just an array of arrays. When you say

```
var array3D = [[[String]]]()
```

What you've created is one empty array, which expects the values you add to it to be of type `[[String]]`. But those inner arrays don't exist yet (much less the inner inner arrays inside them). You can't assign to `array3D[ii]` because `ii` is beyond the bounds of your empty array, you can't assign to `array3D[ii][yy]` because `array3D[ii]` doesn't exist, and you can't append to an array in `array3D[ii][yy]` because `array3D[ii][yy]` doesn't exist.

Because your outer and middle levels of array are fixed in size (5 by 5 by *n*), you could easily create them using `Array.init(count:repeatedValue:)`:

```
let array3D = [[[String]]](count: 5, repeatedValue:
    [[String]](count: 5, repeatedValue: []))
```

(Here the innermost arrays are empty, since it appears you plan to always fill the by appending.)

---

However, it also looks like your use case expects a rather sparse data structure. Why create all those arrays if most of them will be empty? You might be better served by a data structure that lets you decouple the way you index elements from the way they're stored.

For example, you could use a Dictionary where each key is some value that expresses a *(day, lesson, index)* combination. That way the *(day, lesson, index)* combinations that don't have anything don't need to be accounted for. You can even wrap a nice abstraction around your encoding of combos into keys by defining your own type and giving it a subscript operator (as alluded to in appzYourLife's answer).

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for. Btw in Swift 3 its  [[[String]]](repeating: [[String]](repeating: [], count:5), count: 5).

Comment: Thx. I was making a puzzle with a 2D grid and list of elements inside it. I used your logic, but I did it in 3 statements for my own readability.

Answer (score 3):

I slightly modified the Matrix struct provided by [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html)

```
struct Matrix<ElementType> {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [[ElementType]]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: [])
    }
    func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> [ElementType] {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

Now you can write

```
var data = Matrix<String>(rows: 5, columns: 5)
data[0, 0] = ["Hello", "World"]
data[0, 0][0] // Hello
```

Comment: This is the way forward!